# How do I translate a concatenate formula to be able to be used in TextBoxes on a UserForm?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, userform

I'm setting up a user interface on a UserForm that has the capability to click-to-call a customers phone number. I can do this from my Excel sheet already using this formula:

`=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("TEL:",S10))`

I am trying to make this able to be used on my UserForm but I dont know how I would go about doing that. Can hyperlinks even be put on here?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.followhyperlink

Comment: You can format a label to look like a link, then respond to its `Click` event using the link posted by braX.

Comment: To concatenate in VBA, it's just `"TEL:" & Range("S10")` (1 of many different ways)